# Python build path based on current OS [css imports]

Tags: css, linux, django, windows

I am trying to link some CSS in my html (running a Django server) and the problem is that if running on Windows and using the \ (backslash) but then it wouldn't execute properly on Linux (since it uses / (slash)

What is the best way to modify the path in my base.html based on the current executing operating system?

For example if it's Windows it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "\style.css" %}"/>
                                        ^
```

But on Linux:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/style.css" %}"/>
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, configure [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root) and [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-url) in your`settings.py`:

```
import os


# Project root is intended to be used when building paths,
# e.g. ``os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'relative/path')``.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

# Absolute path to the directory where ``collectstatic``
# will collect static files for deployment.
#
# For more information on ``STATIC_ROOT``, visit
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')

# URL to use when referring to static files.
#
# For more information on ``STATIC_URL``, visit
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then you should be able to use

```
{% static 'project/css/style.css' %}
```

which, as far as I know, will take care of compatibility.

Consider reading about [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).